# How to disable 3rd party event loop

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, hook

I use `SetWinEventHook` to handle 3rd party actions, for example `EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART` event.

How can I prevent this app from minimizing? I mean I need something like WinForms `e.Cancel = true;`

How could it work: 3rd party application is minimizing, my app capture this action, cancels it, then ask `Do you really want to minimize %appname%?`, then use SendMessage to minimize it if user clicks on `Yes` button. 
Here is HookCreation:

```
    public Hook(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        lpfnWinEventProc = WinEvent;
        handle = GCHandle.Alloc(lpfnWinEventProc);
        pHook = SetWinEventHook((uint)SystemEvents.EVENT_MIN,
                                (uint)SystemEvents.EVENT_MAX,
                                hWnd,
                                lpfnWinEventProc,
                                0,
                                0,
                                WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT
            );
        if (IntPtr.Zero.Equals(pHook))
            throw new Win32Exception();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only [hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589.aspx) that allows you to filter messages is a [CBT Hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977.aspx). If the list of operations that are reported through this hook is not sufficient, you may find a solution by installing a [GetMsgProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644981.aspx) hook. This allows you to modify the message. Replacing appropriate incoming messages with a `WM_NULL` message is essentially the same as cancelling the message. This only works for messages that are posted to the message queue. Sent messages are not filtered through this hook.